# My toggle is broken. Can you help fix it?

Tags: jquery

The initial part of my code is working. It loads the `-` sign and then changes to a `+` sign when clicked. Or it either loads a multiple `+` signs if needed. Either way, the first initial load is fine. The problem is on the click event. It simply doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.user-email').length == 1) {
        $('.user-email .section-icon').toggleClass('open');
        $('.section-icon').text('-');
    } else if ($('.user-email').length > 1) {
        $('.section-icon').text('+');
    }

    $('.user-email-text').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(".section-icon:contains('-')")) {
            $('.section-icon').text('+');
        } else if ($(".section-icon:contains('+')")) {
            $('.section-icon').text('-');
        }
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
        $(this).siblings('.section-icon').toggleClass('open');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

My fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/6QW2K/

Comment: "It simply doesn't work." Is not an error message nor a problem description.

Comment: Seems your fiddle is missing quite a bit of code.

Comment: you need to add your html to the fiddle for us to understand your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(".section-icon:contains('-')")) {
```

Always evaluates to `true`, you can use `length` property:

```
if ($(".section-icon:contains('-')").length) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f2GZG/

You can also use `text` method instead of using `:contains` selector:

```
$('.section-icon').text(function(i, cur){
   return cur === '+' ? '-' : '+'
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UaGrt/

Comment: Thanks @undefined. All I needed was the length() method. I appreciate it!

Comment: @McGuyverr You are welcome, note that I have changed the selector as it didn't select your element in your current markup.

Comment: If there are more than 1 `user-email` classes printed, it prints multiple `+` signs as expected. Upon clicking those anchors, it changes the `+` and `-` sign for all of those listed. Somehow `$('.section-icon').text('+');` needs to use another method such as parent(), siblings(), or (this) but I'm not sure. Can you help?

Comment: My above comment is for @undefined

Comment: @McGuyverr Yes, of course but I should first see the structure of your markup.

Comment: My fiddle is here @undefined http://jsfiddle.net/ntuth/

Comment: @McGuyverr Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ntuth/1/

Comment: hey @undefined when you click the top `+` on that last fiddle, it collapses the bottom div as well. Can you fix that?

Comment: @McGuyverr It seems you haven't written this code, http://jsfiddle.net/mJT8T/